# how to display one by one images in UIImageView?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am developing a puzzle game where I want display 9 images on my screen and my code is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var xCen :CGFloat  = 53
        var yCen :CGFloat = 94

        for v in 0...2{

            for h in 0...2{

                let Image1 = UIImage(named: "kat_1.gif")
                let myImageView = UIImageView(image: Image1)
                myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 106)
                myImageView.center = CGPointMake(xCen, yCen)
                myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
                self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
                xCen += 106
            }
            xCen = 53
            yCen += 189
        }
    }
```

With this code 1 image is displayed 9 times on screen I do that for testing and It works fine. But I don't know how to display other 8 Images with this. I am doing this from objective-C language tutorial and it says like this:

```
myImageView.Image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"jc_%02i.jpg",h+v*4] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
let Image1 = UIImage(named: "kat_1.gif")
```

You could do use string interpolation (the syntax of `\(expr)` inside the string, where `expr` is some expression or variable to be replaced in the string):

```
let image1 = UIImage(named, "kat_\(h+v*3).gif")
```

or, if you had more than ten and you wanted to have two digit number with leading zero (i.e., you wanted to use printf-style), you could:

```
let filename = String(format: "kat_%02i.jpg", h+v*3)
let Image1 = UIImage(named: filename)
```

Clearly, with either of these, adjust according to the pattern of your names, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using UICollectionView, and populating each of the cells with the image for this kind of applications.